# Sugarcrm - invalid session id via REST - post too large?

Tags: java, rest, sugarcrm

-- Hi everyone

I have a strange behaviour with sugarcrm.
Here the code that i'm using to set a new entry with REST:

```
  public SugarApi(String sugarUrl){
    REST_ENDPOINT = sugarUrl + "/service/v4/rest.php";
    json = new GsonBuilder().create();
    codec = new URLCodec();
  }
```

---

```
    SetEntryRequest req = new SetEntryRequest(sessionId, nameValueListSetEntry, myKind.getModuleName());
    String response = null;
    try {
      response = postToSugar(REST_ENDPOINT+"?method=set_entry&response_type=JSON&input_type=JSON&rest_data="+codec.encode(json.toJson(req)));
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        System.out.println("Set entry failed. Message: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (EncoderException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

where postToSugar is:

```
public String postToSugar(String urlStr) throws Exception {

URL url = new URL(urlStr);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setUseCaches(false);
conn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
throw new IOException(conn.getResponseMessage());
}

// Buffer the result into a string
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
  sb.append(line);
}
rd.close();

conn.disconnect();
if(System.getenv("sugardebug") != null){
  System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
return sb.toString();

}
```

So this code is working fine when the post is small.
the maximum size is the following:

```
{"id":"8c8801c5-ce3b-093c-ee77-514985c19fe1","entry_list":{"account_id":{"name":"account_id","value":"9b37913b-994b-9bc9-4fbf-500e771d845b"},"status":{"name":"status","value":"New"},
"description":{"name":"description","value":"Ceci est un test \/ TICKET A SUPPRIMER"},"priority":{"name":"priority","value":"P1"},
"name":{"name":"name","value":"test longueur post --------------"},"caseorigin_c":{"name":"caseorigin_c","value":"OnLineForm"},"case_chechindate_c":{"name":"case_chechindate_c","value":"2013-01-12"},"type":{"name":"type","value":"ErrorOnCancel"}}}
```

but if the post is longer, the server returns:

```
{"name":"Invalid Session ID","number":11,"description":"The session ID is invalid"}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Looks like your session is timing out before the request is complete.

Comment: I don't think so, because if i add just one character to the field "description" or  "name" at my exemple (see above) i'll get the error. (everytime)

Comment: Thats unusual then. If you have access to the server side examine the logs to see what is getting dumped for the requests that error out.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem with a request I had where the description field had a new line character.  I even urlencoded the newline character and it still gave me the error.  Presumably apache on Sugar's server was breaking the request at the newline which meant the sessionID wasn't found.

My solution was to replace all occurances of `%0A` and `%0D` with `%5Cn`.

`%0A` and `%0D` are different newline characters and `%5Cn` becomes `\n` which is a newline in sugar.

I don't have an extensive list of invalid characters for the rest API.